# how to check linux mint or ubuntu debian version

Tags: linux, ubuntu, linuxmint

How can you check which Debian version Linux Mint or Ubuntu installation is based on using terminal commands? Or I need to make a script.

Comment: uname command ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Mint, but for Ubuntu, the idea of a "base Debian version" is increasingly unrealistic, as it departs ever farther from Debian.

Comment: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list.d/official-package-repositories.list `

Answer (score 4):

```
# cat /etc/issue
Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS \n \l

# lsb_release -da
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
```

Both work on Debian as well, but `lsb_release` needs the package of the same name.

For the base version of Ubuntu:

```
# cat /etc/debian_version
jessie/sid
```

Answer (score 1):

With any debian based system you should be able to look at the various apt sources files under /etc/apt and see the actual release names that are being used by whatever repositories...

But that is only for what that actual distro is pulling.  If you want to know what release of Debian was modified to create the distro you are using, you need to know how they both operate.

Ubuntu pulls from either the unstable/sid repo (regular releases) or from testing (currently stretch) for LTS releases.  Someone created a nice reference list in this answer to a similar question -https://askubuntu.com/questions/445487/which-ubuntu-version-is-equivalent-to-debian-squeeze/445496#445496

Mint pulls from an Ubuntu release and adds a few things, but still actively uses the Ubuntu repos for a lot of things.  When there is an Ubuntu LTS release there is a new associated major release of Mint, followed by a few point releases until the next LTS Ubuntu.